# Do sigops count towards the block weight in SegWit?

Tags: segregated-witness, block-weight, signature-operations

I was just rereading the SegWit benefits page and noticed that the section [Moving towards a single combined block limit](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/01/26/segwit-benefits/#moving-towards-a-single-combined-block-limit) contains an example in which sigops count towards the blockweight.

Did this become part of the final version of SegWit? If not, what happened to this idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The block weight is only calculated from the bytes themselves, not the sigops. Accounting for the sigops would need a hard fork, as explained by the section above the example:

> It is not possible to solve this problem without either a hardfork, or substantially decreasing the block size. Since segwit can’t fix the problem, it settles on not making it worse: in particular, rather than introducing an independent limit for the segregated witness data, instead a single limit is applied to the weighted sum of the UTXO data and the witness data, allowing both to be limited simultaneously as a combined entity.